# How to get length from array as a cass memeber?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a class that has some arrays as members. In some member functions i want to then iterate over said arrays. But when i try to get the length of the array i see the error `non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context`.

I have the line `for(int i = 0; i < this.blue; i++){}` and the array is `private int[][] blue;`

For example:

```
public class M{
    private int[][] arr;

    public static void func(){
         for(int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
         //                 ^^^^ compiler does not like this     
         }
    }
}
```

I understand that i am not looking at an instance of the class, so the value could be anything, but then how will i ever be able to preform such basic operations if i have to know everything before hand?

I have tried to create another member that holds the dimensions, but that leads to the same issue.

Comment: **Please** add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is not enough information to help you.

Comment: I have added a small example.

Comment: public static void func() is a static function. That is, it belongs to the class rather than any instance of that class. private int [][] arr is an instance variable, with a new potential array for each instance of the class. Since static methods do not work on instances, they cannot access instance variables. After all, if there are no instances, there is no arr. If there are multiple instances, which one would they use? The solution is to either make arr a static variable, or make func() a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class M{
    private int[][] arr;

    public void func(){
         for(int i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
         //                 ^^^^ compiler does not like this     
         }
    }
}
```

This removes the error. That is removing static from `func()`. At some point I learned to write it and then stopped questioning it. Thanks for the input in the comments.